# How to eliminate empty rows in excel upload from PHP using PHPExcel upload?

Tags: php, spreadsheet

i am in the middle of the development. i want to eliminate the empty rows while upload a excel from PHP using PHP excel plugin.

```
while($x<=$excel->sheets[0]['numRows']){
    $y=1;
    while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']){
        $cell = isset($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y])
            ? $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] 
            : '';
        if($excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][$y] == $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x][1] ){
            echo $cell;
        } else { 
            echo $cell; 
        }
        $y++;
    } 
    $x++;
}
```

i used this code to get the values from excel to PHP, but if the excel has empty record the result will be modified something like extra cells. how can i fix this.

Comment: Are you really using PHPExcel, or are you using the PEAR Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer (SEW)... it looks more like the latter to me

Comment: Sorry, i used Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer only. how can i eliminate empty rows

Comment: You need to test if every cell in the row array is empty before your second while loop, and only execute that while loop if there are non-empty cells. I'd suggest using array_filter() to get a count of the non-empty cells

Comment: its says : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in

Comment: What says that? What version of PHP are you running? My answer requires a minimum of 5.3.0; but you should be running at least that anyway as anything below that is no longer supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!array_reduce(
    $excel->sheets[0]['cells'][$x],
    function ($state, $value) {
        return $state && !($value > '');
    },
    TRUE
)) {
// execute your while($y<=$excel->sheets[0]['numCols']) loop here
}
```